# Is there any way to monitor a new Application install event on Mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, events, notifications

I'd like run a daemon to monitor this event, how to get the event? notification?

Comment: At the time of installation or after ?

Comment: When a Application moved to /Application.

maybe scan the dir every 10 min is a ugly solution.

Comment: @Summic: Applications can be installed anywhere, not just /Applications. Besides which, most applications don't need to be “installed” anywhere to be used.

Comment: yep, so if there has a system wide notification  would be a great way

Comment: @Summic: There isn't a notification about that because that isn't a thing that can be notified about. FSEvents can detect applications being moved and copied, but neither is required for most applications to be used. The user can and will use applications that they haven't installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [File System Events API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH4-SW4) to observe changes in the file system.

Answer (score 4):

There is a FSEvents API, it looks like the something you need : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Wow. Same time, same idea, same name :)

Comment: Lol :) Actually, there should be system-wide app installation notification, but probably it is not in public SDK.

Comment: @Nikolai's answer is showed on the top. so I had to accepted.

many thanks to Anoop!

Comment: Right choice - when I submitted my answer, his answer was already shown.